# Create a Certificate Revocation List (CRL) with makecert and then bundle it to a .pfx with pvk2pfx

Tags: c#, certificate, client-certificates, x509certificate2

To authenticate an application internally with client certification I have created a Root Certificate and the client certificate using the `makecert` application.

Everything works well but when I use the `X509Certificate2 Verify` method I get the following error:

> The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the
>   certificate

```
X509Certificate2 cert = actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();
cert.Verify();
```

I can get around this by creating a `X509Chain` and then set `X509ChainPolicy` to `RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck`.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();

if (cert == null)
{
    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        ReasonPhrase = "Client Certificate Required"
    };
}
else
{
    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();

    //Needed because the error "The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate" will happen otherwise
    chain.ChainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy()
    {
        RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck,
    };
    try
    {
        var chainBuilt = chain.Build(cert);
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Chain building status: {0}", chainBuilt));

        if (chainBuilt == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = "Client Certificate not valid"
            };
            foreach (X509ChainStatus chainStatus in chain.ChainStatus)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Chain error: {0} {1}", chainStatus.Status, chainStatus.StatusInformation));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

However this got me interested. Is there someway that I can create a `Certificate Revocation List (CRL)` with `makecert` and then bundle it to a .pfx with `pvk2pfx` that will be accepted by `X509Certificate2 Verify`?

Comment: Note that `makecert` is deprecated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx. If you want to rely on `X509Certificate2.Verify()` only, then you are doing it wrong, because your application will accept any world-wide valid certificate.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thanks for input, I have a separate method checking that the certificate is issued from my Root CA. Verify is just a first check that they are sending a valid certificate.

Comment: `X509Certificate2.Verify` is one of the most pointless methods in the framework.  If it returns `true` you probably need to build the same chain it did in order to find out if it's valid in context.  If it returns `false` you might end up building the chain yourself to determine if the "false-ness" is relevant to you or not.  You're better off building the chain object manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on msdn.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648732.aspx

After you have created your Root Certificate run the following command:

```
makecert -crl -n "CN=RootCATest" -r -sv RootCATest.pvk RootCATest.crl
```

Install the CRL file on both the server and client machines. Use MMC to install RootCATes.crl on the client and server machines in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

MMC -> File -> Add or Remove Snap-ins -> Certificates -> My user account

Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates -> Right click -> All tasks -> Import -> RootCATest.crl

I did not manage to bundle it with `pvk2pfx` but after doing this I could run Verify.